# Unexpected behaviour in interactive python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, interactive, python-3.8

```py
>>> r'\'
```

**SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal**

I expected `'\\'` as output.

Comment: `r'\\'`. but make sure to call `print` on the result or the repl will just display `'\\\\'` i.e also the escapes.

Comment: You're getting a syntax error, as you're escaping the second quote, which means there's no closing quote to the regex string, which means the code is invalid.

Comment: @Roy2012 Are you sure it's a "regex string"? I've always thought a prefix `r` means "raw".

Comment: @iBug - you're right - it's 'raw', not 'regex'. Nevertheless, a backslash does escape the next character - but the two characters remain in the string.

Answer (score 0):

As per Python documentation https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals:

> ```
> shortstring     ::=  "'" shortstringitem* "'" | '"' shortstringitem* '"'
> shortstringitem ::=  shortstringchar | stringescapeseq
> shortstringchar ::=  <any source character except "\" or newline or the quote>
> stringescapeseq ::=  "\" <any source character>
> ```

Look at the definition of lexical element `shortstringchar`, it's clear that even in a raw string `r''` or `r""`, a single backslash followed by something would be considered part of the string content, as the LL(1) analyzer descends into `stringescapeseq` instead of reading the "end of string" token, so the following single quote is *not* parsed as "end of raw string".

While not as intuitive, the lexical analyzer (Python so far uses an LL(1) parser) is designed as such.

If you really want a string with only one single backslash, use `'\\'` or `"\\"` (no `r` prefix).

Answer (score 0):

See the last paragraph of the [definition of string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals):

> Even in a raw literal, quotes can be escaped with a backslash, but the backslash remains in the result; for example, `r"\""` is a valid string literal consisting of two characters: a backslash and a double quote; `r"\"` is not a valid string literal (even a raw string cannot end in an odd number of backslashes). **Specifically, *a raw literal cannot end in a single backslash* (since the backslash would escape the following quote character).** Note also that a single backslash followed by a newline is interpreted as those two characters as part of the literal, *not* as a line continuation.